# Java regular expression find all A except B

Tags: java, regex

Here's the case:
I want to use java to remove everything matching `"//[^\n]*"` except for anything that also matches `"\"[^\n]*//[^\n\"]\""`. Pretty much, I need to remove all comment style input, except if it is contained within a string. I tried the regex `"(//[^\n]*)-(\"[^\n]*//[^\n]*\")"`, but that does not replace anything.

Comment: What you need is parser, not regex.

Comment: I am trying to find a simpler way to remove comments. But I guess you're right. +1

Comment: @JamesSmith: so you only want to remove all comments?

Comment: The issue that a Regex may not be able to overcome reasonably is the determination if there is a properly delimited string (or more) to the left of the comment (e.g. `"a" "b" foo "c" // d`) due to the possibly unbounded lookbehund groups.

Comment: @hexafraction: if you can replace with a matching, you don't need lookbehind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from a Perl group many years ago, I modified it a bit to preserve formatting.
There is a simpler version of this that does not preserve formatting.

This one uses Multi-line mode because of the preservation.
Also, if you don't have single quoted strings, take out that part.

It basically match comments or non-comments.
To run it;

- Set Multi-Line mode
- Do a global replace with `$2`

And that's it.

```
      # raw:   ((?:(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/(?:[ \t]*\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//)))?|//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//))|(?=\r?\n))))+)|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|(?:\r?\n|[\S\s])[^/"'\\\s]*)
      # quoted:  "((?:(?:^[ \\t]*)?(?:/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/(?:[ \\t]*\\r?\\n(?=[ \\t]*(?:\\r?\\n|/\\*|//)))?|//(?:[^\\\\]|\\\\(?:\\r?\\n)?)*?(?:\\r?\\n(?=[ \\t]*(?:\\r?\\n|/\\*|//))|(?=\\r?\\n))))+)|(\"(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^\"\\\\])*\"|'(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^'\\\\])*'|(?:\\r?\\n|[\\S\\s])[^/\"'\\\\\\s]*)"

      (                                # (1 start), Comments 
           (?:
                (?: ^ [ \t]* )?                  # <- To preserve formatting
                (?:
                     /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
                     [^*]* \*+
                     (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
                     /                                # End /* .. */ comment
                     (?:                              # <- To preserve formatting 
                          [ \t]* \r? \n                                      
                          (?=
                               [ \t]*                  
                               (?: \r? \n | /\* | // )
                          )
                     )?
                  |  
                     //                               # Start // comment
                     (?:                              # Possible line-continuation
                          [^\\] 
                       |  \\ 
                          (?: \r? \n )?
                     )*?
                     (?:                              # End // comment
                          \r? \n                               
                          (?=                              # <- To preserve formatting
                               [ \t]*                          
                               (?: \r? \n | /\* | // )
                          )
                       |  (?= \r? \n )
                     )
                )
           )+                               # Grab multiple comment blocks if need be
      )                                # (1 end)

   |                                 ## OR

      (                                # (2 start), Non - comments 
           "
           (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*        # Double quoted text
           "
        |  '
           (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*        # Single quoted text
           ' 
        |  (?: \r? \n | [\S\s] )            # Linebreak or Any other char
           [^/"'\\\s]*                      # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                            # or line continuation (escape + newline)
      )                                # (2 end)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Exactly how I need it!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a comment from a single line with the following regex:

```
^(([^\"]*|\"([^\"\\\\]|[\\\\].)*\")*)//.*$
```

And the replace it with the **first matching group**. This regex also takes escaped quotations into account.

In Java this thus reads like:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(([^\"]*|\"([^\"\\\\]|[\\\\].)*\")*)//.*$");
String code = ...;
String result = regex.matcher(code).replaceAll("$1");
```

[**online jdoodle demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/o8).

The regex enforces that once you open a string, you need to close it as well:

```
      start string          stop string
          |                     |
          v                     v
(([^\"]*|\"([^\"\\\\]|[\\\\].)*\")*)
    ^            ^       ^
    |            |       \escapes require at least one extra token
any non-string   non-escape in string
```

You can then remove all such comment by simply splitting the `String` into single lines and loop over the lines and replace these lines with the above discussed method.

Although if you do **programming language processing**, it is better to take advantage of **the parser of that programming language**, or a framework that is used to do such language processing.

Comment: Actually, it replaces comments, but only if the entire line is a comment. Otherwise, if line one is a comment and line 2 is not, everything will be kept.

Comment: @JamesSmith: you need to iterate line per line over the source code. Can you give an example of a line that doesnt work. The jdoodle clearly only removes the comment.

Comment: `"//Comment\n"//Not Comment"`

Comment: @JamesSmith: as said earlier, you must process it line per line. So split it into an array of String (split on `\n`) next `for` each line do a replacement.

Comment: Unfortunately, it also takes out the entire line. So `Stuff //Comment` will get rid of `Stuff`.

Comment: @JamesSmith: if you add this line to the `codes` array of the [**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/o8) you will see, it only removes `// Comment`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79259/discussion-between-james-smith-and-commusoft).